# Why does MySQL not let me declare these variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I had this trigger (instead of insert) that was made for regular SQL, and I'm trying to turn it into MySQL, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
Create Trigger trGenerateNpcID
Before Insert On NPC For Each Row
Begin
    Declare Race varchar(5);
    Declare Name varchar(25);
    Declare Level int;
    Declare Class1 varchar(5);
    Declare Class2 varchar(5);
    Declare City varchar(5);

    Set Race = (Select Race From Inserted);
    Set Name = (Select Name From Inserted);
    Set Level = (Select Level From Inserted);
    Set Class1 = (Select Class1 From Inserted);
    Set Class2 = (Select Class2 From Inserted);
    Set City = (Select City From Inserted);

    Insert into NPC
    Values(Left(Race, 1) + Left(Name, 1) + Left(Level, 1) + next value for sqNpcID,
    Name, Race, Level, Class1, Class2, City);
End;
```

Every time I try to make it, it gives me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: DELIMITER needed. Also - INSERTED is not MySQL syntax, use NEW.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Unless you are looking for implicit datatype conversion there is no need to define variables or select (and if you were selecting mysql could do this in one statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) read the manual for use of OLD and NEW variables.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trGenerateNpcID
    BEFORE INSERT ON NPC FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Race VARCHAR(5);
        DECLARE Name VARCHAR(25);
        DECLARE Level INT;
        DECLARE Class1 VARCHAR(5);
        DECLARE Class2 VARCHAR(5);
        DECLARE City VARCHAR(5);
    
        SET Race = (SELECT Race FROM INSERTED);
        SET Name = (SELECT Name FROM INSERTED);
        SET Level = (SELECT Level FROM INSERTED);
        SET Class1 = (SELECT Class1 FROM INSERTED);
        SET Class2 = (SELECT Class2 FROM INSERTED);
        SET City = (SELECT City FROM INSERTED);
    
        INSERT INTO NPC
        VALUES(LEFT(Race,1) + LEFT(Name,1) + LEFT(Level,1) + NEXT VALUE FOR sqNpcID,
        Name, Race, Level, Class1, Class2, City);
    END;
```

Comment: It should work:- in sql-server/t-sql/mssql yes, but mysql does not have INSERTED table it has NEW. values.

Comment: This still gives the same error, and when I tried replacing Inserted with New, the same error occurred. so I have no clue as to why it fails.

Comment: if you create a simple trigger with the basic an a simple select inside, it works?